# How to combine repetitive similar functions into one function and a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, function, optimization

I have the following code:

```js
var city_valkeakoski = new L.marker([61.2712, 24.0333], {
  icon: new L.divIcon({
    html: '<i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>Valkeakoski',
    iconSize: [20, 20],
    className: 'myicon city'
  }),
  title: "Valkeakoski",
  name: "valkeakoski"
}).on('click', function(e) {
  cityInfo(this)
});
var city_rovaniemi = new L.marker([66.4979, 25.7199], {
  icon: new L.divIcon({
    html: '<i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>Rovaniemi',
    iconSize: [20, 20],
    className: 'myicon city'
  }),
  title: "Rovaniemi",
  name: "rovaniemi"
}).on('click', function(e) {
  cityInfo(this)
});
var city_oulu = new L.marker([65.0127, 25.4714], {
  icon: new L.divIcon({
    html: '<i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>Oulu',
    iconSize: [20, 20],
    className: 'myicon city'
  }),
  title: "Oulu",
  name: "oulu"
}).on('click', function(e) {
  cityInfo(this)
});
[...]
cities.addLayer(city_valkeakoski);
cities.addLayer(city_rovaniemi);
cities.addLayer(city_oulu);
```

I realize that this is wasteful and should better be handled in one function which reads a JSON object or something similar. I just can't figure out how to do this in Javascript, probably because I don't know what expressions to google for... Some examples, links and especially lingo explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array of objects containing all the variable data and loop over it.

```js
const city_data = [{
    city: 'Valkeakoski',
    lat: 61.2712,
    long: 24.0333
  },
  {
    city: 'Rovaniemi',
    lat: 66.4979,
    long: 25.7199
  },
  {
    city: 'Oulu',
    lat: 65.0127,
    long: 25.4714
  }
];

city_data.forEach(({city, lat, long}) => {
  let marker = new L.marker([lat, long], {
    icon: new L.divIcon({
      html: `<i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>${city}`,
      iconSize: [20, 20],
      className: 'myicon city'
    }),
    title: city,
    name: city.toLowerCase()
  });
  cities.addLayer(marker);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that unique variable names are not required so I was looking for a way to programmatically change the variable name.

Comment: Any time you think you need dynamic variables names, you should be using arrays or objects.